# Most reliable SQL Azure connection code?

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I've had more heartache than success with SQL Azure and I'm looking for guidance on the latest methods and most reliable code for creating connections to SQL Azure. My understanding is that

1. There have been significant changes, as recently as Jan 1 2013 that (yet again) affect SQL Azure performance.
2. There have been SQL Azure specific libraries released by MS that make connecting to SQL Azure a lot more reliable and that the need for retry code has been eliminated. Is that correct? I haven't kept up with these changes but my understanding is that it is more reliable.

If it matters to anyone, I currently use the (traditional?) approach of trying to connect to SQL Azure and then checking for an exception and trying the connection one more time. I hope to get replies that will help me eliminate that nonsense.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using the traditional Retry logic that they recommend and have had no real problems. But I generally try more than once if a exception is raised, up to 10 times with a couple of seconds between each retry.

Comment: Wow, 10 times? I thought retries like that were expressly discouraged by MS. Do you have metrics on how often you hit the high-end of that or maybe more than, say, 5 retries? Im guessing that number is higher than most people realize.

Comment: I don't have metrics on the retries but it might be an interesting thing to log. Most of the examples I have seen from MS use 5. I do know that I rarely get connection errors now.

Comment: That might be something to consider indeed. I only do 1 retry per failed attempt.